# command to create custom controls in dotnet 3.5

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, wcf-data-services, wcf

I have  been for an interview, they asked me a question which I could not get the answer for.

1: is there  any  tool/command to create a custom control

2: how  do we create schema in wcf services

3: can  you provide an good link for design patters in C# where i can  go through.

What are good answers to these?

Comment: your questions have very little to do with each other and are also vague. Please try and post one question at the time and be more specific. Create custom controls for what? winforms? wpf? asp.net? As for Wcf are you talking about wsdl metadata or something else? i suggest you head over to http://msdn.microsoft.com/ if you need tips on c#

Comment: "What are good answers to these?" the best answer is "I don't want to work here if you ask questions like those in an interview."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1: is there any tool/command to create a custom control

You can either use an user control or inherit an existing control and modify how its drawn.

> 2: how do we create schema in wcf services

The same way you would do it in any other program?

> 3: can you provide an good link for design patters in C# where i can
>   go through.

The answer to this question is subjective.  MSDN is the best source of information, its the only source I use, thats just me personally.